# if specific row = null, execute query

Tags: mysql

how do i check if the value of a column is null, and only then execute the query? for example:

```
col1 col2 col3
01   abc
```

i run a query which first checks if the record exists or not; if it exists, it should execute the update query and if it doesn't exist, it executes the insert query.  **how do i check if col3 is null** and if it is null, it should execute the update query. .

```
$sql = "SELECT uid FROM `users` WHERE uid = '" . $user_id . "'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql,$conn) or die('Error:' .mysql_error());

    $totalrows = mysql_num_rows($result);
    if($totalrows < 1)
    {
        insertUser($user_id,$sk, $conn);

    }
    else
    {
        updateSessionKey($user_id,$sk,$conn);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE uid = '" . $user_id . "'";
$result = mysql_query($sql,$conn) or die('Error:' .mysql_error());

$totalrows = mysql_num_rows($result);
if($totalrows < 1)
{
    $res = mysql_fetch_array($sql);

    if(!empty($res['col3'])) {

         insertUser($user_id,$sk, $conn);

    }

}
else
{
    updateSessionKey($user_id,$sk,$conn);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Not really checking a value of the column, but I don't think you actually need that.

You need to have `uid` as a `UNIQUE` column. You try to insert a row for a new user with the given `uid`; if it finds the user with the same `uid`, then you do the update instead.

**UPDATE:**

I guess you did not bother to read the link.

I did not test it, but it should be something like this:

```
INSERT INTO users (uid, name, session)
VALUES ('login', 'Real Name', 'SeSsIoN_iD')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE session='SeSsIoN_iD'
```

This will insert the user if he does not exist, and if he does, it will set a new session key. OR, if you want to preserve the old session key if he already has one,

```
INSERT INTO users (uid, name, session)
VALUES ('login', 'Real Name', 'SeSsIoN_iD')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE session=IFNULL(session, 'SeSsIoN_iD')
```

One query, not three. You were *not* already doing it.

Comment: i'm already doing this. i need specifically what i asked about.

Comment: Going by your snippet, you're *not* already doing this, and you probably didn't even open the link. I have updated the answer with explicit instructions.

Comment: ahh. .alrite, i get you now. thanks for this, but i need to update more than the key, especially if a particular column of a user is null. the thing is, i already have a database with some user details but some of the fields were not updated before. now, i would like to update them with their details when they return to the page. those whose details already exist, i'm just updating their session key; while those whose don't, it should check if the column is null, and then update accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

Is this what you mean?

- If the record does not exist -> insert.
- If the record does exist and its col3 is null -> update
- If the record does exist, but its col3 is not null -> do nothing?

That could be achieved like this (untested):

```
$sql = "SELECT uid, col3 FROM `users` WHERE uid = '" . $user_id . "'";
$result = mysql_query($sql,$conn) or die('Error:' .mysql_error());

$totalrows = mysql_num_rows($result);
if($totalrows < 1)
{
    insertUser($user_id,$sk, $conn);
}
else
{
    $col3value = mysql_result($result, 0, 'col3');
    if (is_null($col3value))
    {
        updateSessionKey($user_id,$sk,$conn);
    }
}
```

Comment: tried this. somehow even if the value is null, it doesn't go to the if statement. is something wrong?

Comment: The code looks like it should work... You've changed col3 into the real column name everywhere? Else you could try $col3value = mysql_fetch_array($result)->['col3']; with the name replaced, of course.